# how to skip an element to go into json string in an html page data-binded using knockout.js

Tags: html, json, knockout.js

```
<div data-bind='a'></div> 
<div data-bind='b'></div>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

I want 'b' not to be saved in json string..

Comment: Lots of ways to do this one.  You can even just do `ko.toJSON($root, ['a'], 2)`.  Check out about 18:12 into the video here for some other options: https://vimeo.com/51103092

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) ko plugin:

```
<div data-bind='text: a'></div> 
<div data-bind='text: b'></div>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.mapping.toJSON($root, {ignore: ['b']})"></pre>​
```